# Do I have to keep explicit references for return values from GetCell() and GetViewForHeader() in UITableViewSource in MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I remember that it was (still is?) necessary in MonoTouch to keep explicit references to `UITableViewCells` returned by `UITableViewSource.GetCell()` to avoid collection of the managed cells. Wit regards to this issue, I have some questions:

- As of MonoTouch 5.2.12: is it still required to keep an `ArrayList()` with the managed cells created and returned be GetCell()?
- If I use Storyboards and dynamic cell prototypes, I never explicitly create a `UITableViewCell` but use `DequeueReusableCell()` only. What about this case?
- What about `GetViewForHeader()`? Do I have to keep references to the views I return from that method? Or is MonoTouch internally taking care of this?

Comment: I don't think I've ever had to keep a reference to a Cell.

Comment: Yes, it is required - see here (Section "New Reference Counting System"): http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/releases/MonoTouch_5/MonoTouch_5.1

Comment: The example given seems to be a fairly specific scenario where the cell had a delegate.  If the cell doesn't have a delegate, I think you can get away without maintaining the reference.

Comment: No. The example says that the cell will be collected together with the delegate and that is an issue.

Comment: I've never stored references to UITableCells (even custom ones) and never had issues.  Now I do keep the UITableViewSource around, because if it got collected there would be problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the only scenario where you need to hold a reference to individual cells is if you have both a delegate on them *and* the cell is not a custom class.

If you subclass UITableViewCell, you shouldn't need to hold any references.

If you don't set any delegates, you also shouldn't need to hold any references.

Comment: But if I'm using a standard cell and add a custom view as subview, and that custom view has a button with a delegate, I have to keep a ref? How can I prevent millions of cell refs? When to release again?

Comment: That's a good question and I don't know... I would recommend making a custom cell class which would likely eliminate this issue. Hopefully Rolf or Sebastien can answer that question more definitively.

Answer (score 0):

If it's any help, MonoTouch.Dialog doesn't keep a reference to the Cell either, atleast not that I recall seeing!. Just makes it and passes it on. (posted on the question, too)

thinking about it, you should NOT keep references to cells, because they are designed to be reused.... so you may not get the same cell back in the next GetCell / GetCellForReuse type call.